# Parts of mesh become invisible at certian angles Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, mesh, fbx, 3d-model

I am importing an fbx model but parts of it are invisible in the scene And game at certain angles.

Attached image SS-1 = the full model - You can see that some parts of the mesh are invisible Attached image SS-2 = closeup of an invisible mesh selected
Attached image SS-3 = Main Camera Settings
Attached image SS-4 = Model import settings

Any ideas what's going on?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you make it yourself? are you sure that normals point in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normals of your mesh are not set properly, so the culling algorithm treats it as a back-face that should not be rendered.

If you can edit the model so that you can inverse the normals that would work. Most modeling tools have convenient tools or direct routines for "flipping normals". However, if that is not possible, a trick is to [change the culling settings from your material](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-CullAndDepth.html): When the culling mode is set to Cull Back (which is the default setting), the polygons that are not facing the camera are not rendered. Then, for the mesh that is not visible, you can change the culling property from Cull Back to Cull Front. This way it will be visible.

The caveat is that most of the time material properties might be overlooked as Cull Front and No Cull settings are not as common as Cull Back. Also, performance-wise, you will have a different shader running because of that mesh.

Comment: Tried normals but it made some parts visible and other invisible. 

Cull settings worked but Cull Off shader would be bad performance wise, right? So any other suggestions?

Comment: If you invert the normals of the *entire* mesh, that is the expected behavior. You should select the triangles whose normals are wrong and invert them only instead. Cull Off shader may or may not be detrimental to the performance, and it depends on many other factors as well: You may try the [GPU Profiler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ProfilerGPU.html) to assess the impact of on the performance.

Answer (score 2):

Try two-sided shader, as suggested [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/922846/unity-5-and-two-sided-materials.html)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I found for this problem is:

1.Select the object that's going invisible on certain angles.

2.Navigate to Mesh Renderer > Render Face > Both

The problem should be solved now
My Unity version is 2019.3